# Vertical alignment of inf subscripts without vphantom

Tags: phantom

I was wondering whether it would be possible to align the index of multiple infimums (or supremums, or limits..) without recurring to the `\vphantom` command - I feel somehow it's kind of "cheating".

Here is a short MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\inf_{v, w \in V} \bigg(\inf_{\tilde v, \tilde w \in \widetilde V} v + w - (\tilde v + \tilde w)\bigg)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\inf_{\vphantom{\widetilde V}v, w \in V} \bigg(\inf_{\tilde v, \tilde w \in \widetilde V} v + w - (\tilde v + \tilde w) \bigg)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And this is the behaviour I would like to get without the `\vphantom`(equation (2) is well aligned)
[image]

Comment: `\bigg` is definitely too big; try `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr). The alignment needs the phantom, or changing the font parameter responsible for the distance, but this might have adverse effects in other places where you don't want a big gap.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I copy-pasted an actual part of a draft paper of mine (making it simpler), and I need a `\Bigl(` `\Bigr)` inside the `\bigg` parentheses. I agree that stand-alone like this it's a bit too big.

Comment: It's not necessary to use larger parentheses at each nesting level. In any case, start at the lowest size possible. Note `\biggl` and `\biggr` behave correctly as regards to spacing, which `\bigg` doesn't.

Comment: I agree - thanks - with the left/right specification of parentheses. Nonetheless, I think that nesting big-to-small parentheses, especially when it helps "covering" the inside symbols, enhances readability of rather complex formulae (the simple example I posted here is _not_ a case of this)

Comment: I presume you speak of the vertical placement of the subscript.  Do you require the syntax to remain the same?  If not, a `stackengine` macro could easily be defined (using an argument rather than an underscore) to set the subscript at a given baseline distance below the `\inf` rather than with a fixed amount of white space (as is currently done).

Comment: Thanks, I think your strategy is summarized in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I am not addressing the paren height issue that others have drawn attention to, but rather the vertical elevation of the underscript across terms of an equation.

The `\vphantom` is required because the subscript placement provides a fixed gap of white space between the operator and the underscript.  This is generally a good thing, because it allows underscripts of various heights to be set in a reasonable way.

The drawback is that if an two operators have underscripts of slightly different heights, the baselines of the underscripts are not aligned.

Here, instead, I define a macro `\finf` (fixed-underset `\inf`) that takes an argument, `\finf{...}`, which it uses in lieu of the `\inf_{...}` syntax, and fixes the baselineskip between the operator and the underscript.  An optional argument is also provided to specify the baselineskip.

Thus, the `\vphantom` is avoided and `\finf{...}` takes no more key strokes than `\inf_{...}`.

EDITED to provide a generic macro `\fop` for doing this to any math operator, and show how to set it up for not only `\finf`, but also `\fsum`.  With this approach, the underscript baselines will always be aligned, regardless of their local height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amscd}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\fop[3][9pt]{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{#1}%
  {\displaystyle#2}{\scriptstyle#3}{U}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}\limits}
\newcommand\finf[2][9pt]{\fop[#1]{\inf}{#2}}
\newcommand\fsum[2][13pt]{\fop[#1]{\sum}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\centering
inf (no vphantom)
\begin{equation}
\inf_{\mathstrut v, w \in V} \bigg(\inf_{\tilde v, \tilde w \in \widetilde V} v + w - (\tilde v + \tilde w)\bigg)
\end{equation}\medskip

inf (vphantom)
\begin{equation}
\inf_{\vphantom{\widetilde V}v, w \in V} \bigg(\inf_{\tilde v, \tilde w \in \widetilde V} v + w - (\tilde v + \tilde w) \bigg)
\end{equation}\medskip

finf
\begin{equation}
\finf{\mathstrut v, w \in V} \bigg(\finf{\tilde v, \tilde w \in \widetilde V} v + w - (\tilde v + \tilde w)\bigg)
\end{equation}\medskip

fsum
\begin{equation}
\fsum{\mathstrut v, w \in V}^n \bigg(\fsum{\tilde v, \tilde w \in \widetilde V}^n v + w - (\tilde v + \tilde w)\bigg)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In the image below, red lines have been added just to highlight the alignment of underscript baselines that are of slightly different vertical height
[image]